# Why does a file (.py) on pycharm run a different file than the one that’s currently on?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running the bottom piece of code on a file titled clusters.py and it doesn’t use the module pygame. However, it is running another file name random.py that does use pygame and subsequently showing the execution run of that file. Somewhere, I have read that if the files are similar then pycharm may treat them alike. I don’t think that’s the issue here. Can someone please explain why this is happening and what can be done.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(features[:,0], features[:,1], s=2**7, c=labels, edgecolors = 'white', alpha = 0.85, cmap = 'autumn')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel(date.feature_names[0])
plt.ylabel(data.feature_names[1])
plt.scatter(k_means.cluster_centers_[:,0],k_means.cluster_centers_[:,1], s=2**6, marker = 's', c = 'white')
plt.scatter(mb_k_means.cluster_centers_[:,0], mb_k_means.cluster_centers_[:,1], s=2**8, marker = '*', c = 'white')
for class_no in range(0,3):
    plt.annotate(data.target_names[class_no],(features[3+50*class_no,0],features[3+50*class_no,1]))
    plt.show()
```

"No module named 'pygame' "  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/julia/.PyCharmEdu2019.2/config/scratches/Cluster.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\julia\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "C:\Users\julia\.PyCharmEdu2019.2\config\scratches\random.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Is `Python 3.7 (test)` the same interpreter as specified in `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter`?

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that pycharm created a project named after the file you want to run, but the script selected to run is random.py. This has happened to me before. You have go to Run > Edit Configurations to change what script you want to run.

Comment: I've added a screen shot. There wasn't anything that was applied under edit configuration as there wasn't any new features to add or change that weren't there already. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's weird. The only idea I have is to create a completely new python file. Make it run just a print statement so you're sure the pygame error doesn't happen. Then just copy paste all the contents of Cluster.py into this new file. If the pygame error happens again, something Cluster.py calls is using pygame, or at least a file used by Cluster.py is calling something that uses pygame.